# SQL trigger after insert to delete

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

Good day. I do not know where to start only what I want to do.

The website program I'm usig is adding stock to the SQL database when I do udpate. It update existing product but insert (add) stock if it does not exist. Long story short and lots of reasons the best and quickest fix will be either get 'n trigger for before insert or add or update to check on line. At the moment I run this line every day after update from the myphpadmin.

```
DELETE FROM `abgu_products` WHERE `date_available` = 0000-00-00
```

I know nothing about triggers. Can someone please show me how to set up a trigger that will not allow adding/inserting/updating the item into the SQL databse if: `date_available` = 0000-00-00

Thanks for reading and helping.

Enjoy your day.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to triggers, many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Have you considered defining a CONSTRAINT on the table?  You could look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: Do realize 0000-00-00 means 0000 minus 00 minus 00, i.e a calculation with the integer value 0 as result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tagged the question with `mysql` based on the mentioning of "myphpadmin", the use of the dreaded backticks and invalid date values

Comment: See here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html for error handling in mysql (includes in triggers) see here for triggers https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html. Note in mysql you need seperate triggers of insurt,update,delete. Also you cannot action a table which fired the trigger in the trigger other than to adjust the NEW. and OLD. values